# Google Maps v3 hide elements (roads, roadsigns, etc)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I found a code snippet on http://www.41latitude.com/post/1268734799/google-styled-maps:

```
[
  {
    featureType: "administrative",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "poi",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "water",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "road",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  }
]
```

I should be able to use it in my maps, but is there somebody who can tell me how I can use this snippet? I can't find anything about it in the API of Google Maps V3.

Comment: I really don't see much on the page, it looks like they are using the different basemaps road, satelite, etc. They do manipulate the styling options as already detailed.

Comment: It's here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As [@ceejayoz suggested in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024672/google-maps-v3-hide-elements-roads-roadsigns-etc/4024721#4024721), you are trying to use the new [Styled Map features](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#StyledMaps) of the [v3 Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/). Here's a very basic example of how you could use the above style in a simple map:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps Dark Water Style Demo</title> 
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
   <div id="map" style="width: 550px; height: 300px;"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 
     var myStyle = [
       {
         featureType: "administrative",
         elementType: "labels",
         stylers: [
           { visibility: "off" }
         ]
       },{
         featureType: "poi",
         elementType: "labels",
         stylers: [
           { visibility: "off" }
         ]
       },{
         featureType: "water",
         elementType: "labels",
         stylers: [
           { visibility: "off" }
         ]
       },{
         featureType: "road",
         elementType: "labels",
         stylers: [
           { visibility: "off" }
         ]
       }
     ];

     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       mapTypeControlOptions: {
         mapTypeIds: ['mystyle', google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN]
       },
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(30, 0),
       zoom: 3,
       mapTypeId: 'mystyle'
     });

     map.mapTypes.set('mystyle', new google.maps.StyledMapType(myStyle, { name: 'My Style' }));
   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

You may also want to check out the [Google Maps APIs Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com) which will allow you to graphically edit styles.

Comment: Great, this example was a good example and gave me the solution.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this: `featureType: ["poi", "transit"]` i.e. selecting them all and then disabling the visibility for them all at the same time?

Comment: Yes you can, use `featureType: "all"`

Answer (score 9):

I know this is 5 years old, but I stumbled across this and the accepted solution is much more complex than needed in my opinion.  Given the JSON in the original post, this is how you would apply the style to an existing map:

```
var mapStyle = [
  {
    featureType: "administrative",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "poi",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "water",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "road",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  }
]

//create map
var map = new google.maps.Map(...); //This assumes you already have a working map

//set style
map.set('styles', mapStyle);
```

Answer (score 0):

The page you linked to includes a link to [the Google Maps API documentation for this feature](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#StyledMaps).

Comment: Ok, missed the link. Like my Girlfriend says: I'm a good searcher, but a bad finder!