# GOOGLE MAPS URL PARAMETER HIDE LABEL

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, browser

Im developing an Ios and Android App which through a web browser shows a position in a google map. Such position is provided as http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%s,%s. 
The space in the webbrowser for show such map and position is too small, so the search box label and the how to arrive label occupy the entire map, so the map and position is not visible. Is under such labels. 
I have been testing all the google maps url parameters and i cant find the right one to hide such label.

Any suggestion for hide such labels

Regards

Comment: No need to shout.. ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024672/google-maps-v3-hide-elements-roads-roadsigns-etc You can find tips on Google maps styling here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks MHakvoort, i found the solution:

```
var
  point:string;
begin
  point:='<!DOCTYPE html>'
+ '<html>'
+ '  <head>'
+ '    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">'
+ '    <meta charset="utf-8">'
+ '    <title>Displaying text directions with <code>setPanel()</code></title>'
+ '    <style>'
+ '      html, body, #map-canvas {'
+ '        height: 100%;'
+ '        margin: 0px;'
+ '        padding: 0px'
+ '      }'
+ '      #panel {'
+ '        position: absolute;'
+ '        top: 5px;'
+ '        left: 50%;'
+ '        margin-left: -180px;'
+ '        z-index: 5;'
+ '        background-color: #fff;'
+ '        padding: 5px;'
+ '        border: 1px solid #999;'
+ '      }'
+ '    </style>'
+ '    <style>'
+ '      #directions-panel {'
+ '        height: 100%;'
+ '        float: right;'
+ '        width: 30%;'
+ '        overflow: auto;'
+ '      }'
+ ''
+ '      #map-canvas {'
+ '        margin-right: 4px;'
+ '      }'
+ ''
+ '      #control {'
+ '        background: #fff;'
+ '        padding: 5px;'
+ '        font-size: 14px;'
+ '        font-family: Arial;'
+ '        border: 1px solid #ccc;'
+ '        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.4);'
+ '        display: none;'
+ '      }'
+ ''
+ '      @media print {'
+ '        #map-canvas {'
+ '          height: 500px;'
+ '          margin: 0;'
+ '        }'
+ ''
+ '        #directions-panel {'
+ '          float: none;'
+ '          width: auto;'
+ '        }'
+ '      }'
+ '    </style>'
+ '    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>'
+ '    <script>'
+ 'var directionsDisplay;'
+ 'var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();'


+ 'function initialize() {'
+ '  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();'

+ '  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.837017059326,-2.6883459091187);'

+ '  var mapOptions = {'
+ '    zoom: 15,'
+ '    center: myLatlng'
+ '  };'

+ '  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(''map-canvas''),'
+ '      mapOptions);'

+ '    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({'
+ '        position: myLatlng,'
+ '        map: map'
+ '    });'
+ ''
+ '}'
+ 'google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, ''load'', initialize);'
+ ''
+ '    </script>'
+ '  </head>'
+ '  <body>'
+ '    <div id="map-canvas"></div>'
+ '  </body>'
+ '</html>';

  WebBrowser5.LoadFromStrings(point,'');
```

With such code, you can get a google map inside a webbrowser without headers.